# Updating a map after every loop iteration in C++ 11

Tags: c++, c++11

I have a loop, which is calculating the size of second member of the `p`,

where `p` is `std::pair<const std::string, std::set<std::string>>`

```
for (const auto& p : ref)
    std::cout << p.second.size() << endl;
```

Now I want to create another map `cnt` (`std::map<std::string, int> cnt;`), 
which saves `p.first` and `p.second.size()` after every iteration.

How can I do that?

Comment: Please format the code in your question appropriately

Comment: Unclear question. Show the declaration and the function code, so put a dozen of lines at least (each prefixed by four spaces at least) in your question. Please **edit your question** to improve it

Comment: Show also the declaration of `ref`  and of `cnt`; you probably should give a dozen more lines of your source code to make your question understandable and self-contained

Comment: Apologies, the format was incorrectly submitted.

Answer (score 2):

Declare `std::map<std::string, int> cnt;` 
Before you iterate through whatever data structure you are using to store the pairs. While you are iterating though this structure, simply put

```
cnt[p.first] = p.second.size();
```